# Optimizing Join and Group BY

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, group-by

I Got a Query with 2 Joins and 1 group by .

My Problem is that without the join the keys of the table could be used and the Query is super fast.

Through the join Mysql first Joins the Query and can't use the Key anymore. 
Instead it uses the Primary Keys for join.

Is there anything one could do to force sql to do the Group by first and afterwards join with the primary key ?

The first join is quite slow the second one is an easy join.

Does MySQL Optimize the Query by itself ?

```
select Count(db.Time1) as Value0,
 Count(db.Time2) as Value1,
 Count(db.Time3) as Value2, 
 Count(db.Time4) as Value3,
 t_ref_kws.jahr_kw as XAchse from db
 inner join t_kenner on t_kenner.Request_ID = db.Request_ID
inner join t_ref_kws on db.Time1 = t_ref_kws.id_t_ref_kw 
where t_kenner.Thema = 2 and db.Time1 > 300 group by db.Time1
```

Thanks in Advance :)

[image: Explain statement]

As you see it uses the primary key twice but than uses temporary and filesort as shown in extra. I think this is the group by statement - which makes the query slow

Comment: Using primary keys for join shouldn't be slow. Please post your explain output and also post your table structs

Comment: I do not get the point of the query: it groups by on db.Time1, yet db.Time1 is counted in the select list. You also have t_ref_kws.jahr_kw field in the select list, but you neither group by on it, nor it is parameter of a group by function.

Comment: The Point of the Query is to create a Diagram with the db.time1 column as the xaxis. So by counting the amount of request which occured to a certain time its possible to do so. db.time1 is basically just a reference it could also be t_ref_kws.jahr_kw since both have the same datevalues over time. Explain is coming

Comment: That query is too strange to try to optimize.  You `COUNT(time1)` without listing it.  You include `jahr_kw` in the `SELECT`, but don't `GROUP BY` it.  You have `JOINs`, which probably inflate the row count, then `COUNT` the inflated values.  Please debug it, then we can discuss performance.